# Radioactive decay differential equations

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to form a differential equation between two different isotopes, Uranium-238 and Thorium-234. 
The rate of decay of an isotope is promotional to the amount present. So that: 
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = -kx
$$
Where x is the amount of Uranium-238 and k is the constant if proportionality. Also,
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = -cx
$$
Where y is the amount of Thorium-234 and c is the constant if proportionality.

I have also been told that:
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} + cy = kxe^{-kt}
$$

I am trying to find the general solution to the differential equation above. I have found the integrating factor which is:

$$
Ae^{ct}
$$
And I have multiplied all the terms by the integrating factor to get:

$$
Ae^{ct}\frac{dy}{dt} + Ae^{ct}cy = kxe^{-kt}Ae^{ct}
$$

Now using the product rule backwards we get: 
$$
\frac{dAe^{ct}y}{dt} = kxe^{-kt}Ae^{ct}
$$

Then I integrated to get:
$$
Ae^{ct}y = \int({kxe^{-kt}Ae^{ct}})dt
$$
$$
Ae^{ct}y = \frac{kxe^{-kt}Ae^{ct}}{c-k}
$$

Thus,
$$
y=\frac{kxe^{-kt}Ae^{ct}}{(c-k)(Ae^{ct})}
$$

however, it seems that I have done something wrong since the answer is:

$$
y = Ae^{ct}+\frac{kxe^{-kt}}{k-c}
$$

Could you tell me where I may have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I might have solved it.

$$
\frac{dy}{dt}+cy=kxe^{kt}
$$

Then the integrating factor must be:
$$
R= e^{ct}
$$

Multiplying the integrating factor through:
$$
e^{ct}\frac{dy}{dt}+cye^{ct}=xke^{ct-kt}
$$
Then using the product rule backwards:
$$
\frac{d(e^{ct}y)}{dt}=kxe^{ct-kt)
$$
Integrating both sides gets us:

$$
e^{ct}y = \frac{kxe^{ct-kt}}{c-k}+A
$$

thus,
$$
y=Ae^{-ct}+\frac{kxe^{-kt}}{c-k}
$$